# Activity feed with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance, feed

I'm in the making of some kind of "activity stream/feed" using PHP and MySQL.

I got one table for the stream which simply just stores the type of the activity and the timestamp. I then need to lookup the actual data for the activity which can be find in various tables (depending on the activity-type). The stream should be able to handle hundreds of users and I therefore need it to perform well. The options I got:

- Get the stream table - loop through in PHP with some kind of switch and then call SQL for the appropriate activity data (for each activity). (Slow)
- Make one big SQL sentence with some joins taking all the activity data in one request. Still doing the switch in PHP but without having to call SQL again. (Is this slow for big tables?)
- Using some kind of views with MySQL - I haven't done this before.
- Using multiple SQL calls to get all activity data and store them in PHP arrays and from there do the switching.

Do I have any other options? What would be the best approach in terms of performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may perform a data-driven `JOIN` with a single query. Essentially, you would `JOIN` every needed subtable and then select, by aliasing, the content from the table you needed. Assuming 1 is activity_drink, 2 is activity_eat and 3 is activity_sports and all subtables have the column `content`, which you'd like to fetch:

```
SELECT a.`timestamp`,
    CASE a.`activity_type`
        WHEN 1 THEN ad.`content`
        WHEN 2 THEN ae.`content`
        WHEN 3 THEN asp.`content`
    END AS content
FROM activities AS a
LEFT JOIN activity_drink AS ad ON (ad.`activity_id` = a.`activity_id`)
LEFT JOIN activity_eat AS ae ON (ae.`activity_id` = a.`activity_id`)
LEFT JOIN activity_sports AS asp ON (asp.`activity_id` = a.`activity_id`)
```

This would basically denormalize your tables at select time. You could also convert it to a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) for ease of access. It shouldn't be too expensive, assuming you've properly set up foreign keys, IDs and/or `UNIQUE` indexes (MySQL will notice no matching rows in the table and "ignore it" - selecting a NULL row). I haven't tested it quite properly, since I lack any data and had to assume, but the snippet should be basically functioning.

I would, however, like to mention that I am personally wary of having to do data-driven joins. The correct way to do normalisation in this case would be to find the largest common set of attributes and put them into an `activities` table. If then necessary, you could add extra information to adjoining tables. Generally speaking, however, if multiple tables use the same data, you should probably move it into the main column, unless it's absolutely necessary not to.

Answer (score 1):

My implemented solution has 7 different types of content types all stored in separate tables, but I have **1 activity/feed table**.

**My Solution -**
Using **mySQL5.7 I take advantage of the JSON field**. I have a job which selects the different types of content and inserts a row into the activity table and using **mysql JSON_OBJECT()** it stores that data as json in the data column and then my application is what manipulates that json and displays as it should. The JSON data only has the relevant data it needs for that content type so no null values

- id | contentType | data(JSON) | created | status

So it means I have no inner joins, no none scalable table with loads of null fields.

I was easily able to add more content types without changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

if the activity stream is not too long (a few records, not thousands) I would go for just one query, if the tables are indexed correctly, the query should be fast enough. In case, you can make unions with your tables, I guess this query shouldn't be that expensive.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM stream 
    INNER JOIN type1 ON stream.id = type1.stream_id
  LIMIT 50

  UNION

  SELECT * FROM stream 
    INNER JOIN type1 ON stream.id = type1.stream_id
  LIMIT 50

  UNION

  ...
)
ORDER BY stream.timestamp_field
LIMIT 50
```

As another solution, if you don't have many type tables, you could make a query for each table type, and then merge results. But you'll have to order the merged results with PHP.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM stream INNER JOIN type1 ON stream.id = type1.stream_id";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM stream INNER JOIN type2 ON stream.id = type2.stream_id";
...
```

What size are the results you want to obtain?? how you want to order the results?? maybe performance is not an issue by limiting your query results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First of all I don't think a UNION could to the trick cause my tables with activity data is very different. That's why I'm joining all the tables (giving me a lot of columns). My guess is that hundreds of users have activity streams of perhaps 50-100 rows. The ordering is just by a timestamp.

Comment: thats not such a big query result if tables are indexed properly. you could join the tables without problems. if possible try to limit the results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply, but if the activity feed is part of a larger application, it may make sense to use an external service like Collabinate (http://www.collabinate.com).